# No HTML email after installing Enigmail in Thunderbird 3.1.10

Tags: mac, thunderbird, html, gnupg, enigmail

I am running Thunderbird 3.1.10 on Mac OS X 10.6.7, and have just installed GnuPG and Enigmail extensions per the official website's instructions.

Unfortunately, all the emails I receive now are all in plain text, including the HTML emails. What setting can I change to make HTML emails I receive display correctly again?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps it is a couple of settings in T-Bird and maybe Firefox? The 2nd post in this forums spells it out:

> In Firefox, go to View menu, select
>   Page Style, and make sure "Basic Page
>   Style" is selected, NOT "No Style".
>
> In Thunderbird, you'd go to View menu,
>   select Message Body As and make sure
>   "Original HTML" is selected.
>
> These are changes Enigmail ask you if
>   you want it to make during the Setup
>   Wizard process.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1464402